# Python keeps writing a unix-style newline even though I explicitly use \r\n

Tags: python, python-2.7, line-breaks

**Update:** solved, the issue was in the email sending code. The file saved to local disk was fine, but then the email sending code read it in the non-binary mode, and converted the line breaks.

---

I am trying to generate a text file with Windows-style line breaks (CR LF, \r\n) using this code:

```
f = open(path_and_filename, 'w+')
for line in file_contents:
    f.write(line + '\r\n')
```

However, the resulting file still has only the LF (\n) line break character, I checked in a hex editor and it is displayed incorrectly (all text in one line) on Windows.

Is there some hidden setting that overrides my Windows-style line breaks?

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: have you tried with open('tmpfile', 'w', newline='\r\n') as f:

Comment: Or using `f.write(line + b'\r\n')`. Using a byte string.

Comment: @clmno `b'\r\n'` did not work :(

Comment: Is your editor converting it to LF? Your code works for me (Ubuntu 18.04 py 3 and 2.7)

Comment: For sure you can rb --> read as binary. Another thing is try to remove the \n from the line. Do basically   line = line.strip('\n') and then write the line + \r\n. It might be that when you open the file in Windows it recognize that the \n is the return instead of \r\n

Comment: @clmno nope, the file is sent via Gmail and when I download the attachment and open it in the hex editor, the line breaks are gone (only \n left). I will try opening the file in binary mode

Comment: Maybe gmail is messing with the attachment? Try sending it in a password protected zip file to prevent gmail from being able to see the file.

Comment: @Farhan.K Bingo, you were almost right. The code that writes the file works fine; it was the code that send the email (it read the file using the non-binary mode).

Comment: Ah okay. I thought you were sending it manually in Gmail. Glad you solved it